# Android Keyboard not hidden after form submit

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

You create a form with the input field and "Clear" button and you expect that:

- When you type something and hit "Go/Search" button on mobile keyboard the keyboard should be hidden.
- And when you click on "Clear" button the input should be cleared but keyboard stays open.

Funny thing is that it works t**otally opposite**: the keyboard would be opened after submitting the form and disappear after cleaning the input.

Is there any way to make it "right"?

The code, HTML

```
<form id="form">
  <input id="input" type="search" autofocus />
</form>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
```

and JS

```
document.getElementById('form')
  .onsubmit = function(e) { e.preventDefault() }

document.getElementById('clear')
  .onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var input = document.getElementById('input')
    input.value = ''
    // trying to focus to open keyboard, but it didn't work
    input.focus()
  }
```

Demo https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rpGjGe?editors=1011

Answer (score 1):

I see how you could see it that way, but it's a matter of how certain events work by default in JS.

When you click on your "clear" button, what you are doing is focusing out of your input, which in turn is what makes the keyboard disappear. Since you are no longer typing on your input, the keyboard goes away.

However, when you click on "Go/continue/submit" button, the focus remains on the input until the correspondent form action triggers.

I would either:

1. Force the focusout event on the input on submit, and focusin on the input after clicking on "clear", same as you are doing now; OR
2. Add a submit button to trigger the form submit event. That would remove the focus off the input and place it on the submit button.

Below is a code snippet for Option 1:

```js
document.getElementById('form')
  .onsubmit = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('input').blur();
};

document.getElementById('clear').onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  input.value = '';
  input.focus();
};
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="input" type="search" autofocus />
</form>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
```

See this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Marventus/pen/YYrNdv?editors=1010) for reference.